# Curl to check logins entered

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use a PHP script to put logins and passwords and test what is the right username and password, can anyone show me how i can do that please?

```
username=user1, password=passuser1, gender=1
```

to example.com

and after that I'm assuming that curl will return to me a response that this is correct or OK.

```
Note: the process must be done more than 20 or 30 times.
```

Comment: You should supply the code you're currently using.

Comment: We're not going to help you hack into someone else's system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a hint on how to do it, but i will not do it for you, because you are trying to brute force a website and i can't help you with this however this is an example:

```
<?php
//
// A very simple PHP example that sends a HTTP POST to a remote site
//

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/tester.phtml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

// in real life you should use something like:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
//          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }

?>
```

If you need more examples you can look at the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php